# Connecting to a weblogic cluster via JPDA

Tags: debugging, weblogic, remote-debugging, jpda

I have a weblogic cluster set up across two machines in a staging environment. I'd like to set up JPDA on at least one of the weblogic instances so I can debug remotely. Generally I use wlst.sh and jython scripts to startup the cluster via:

```
startNodeManager(...)
nmConnect(...)
nmStart(MyAdminServer)
connect(...) #connect to the admin server
start(...) #start the cluster
```

Where should I put the `-Xdebug Xrunjdwp:transport...` incantation so that I can attach to one of the weblogic instances? I had no problem setting this up on a single instance through my domain's `startWebLogic.sh`, but it doesn't seem to work with the cluster.

From here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2233816 it looks like I want to put the debug string in `startManagedWeblogic.sh` but that doesn't seem to work with my jython script either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/server_start/nodemgr.html#1081870:

```
 4. The Administration Server obtains the domain configuration from its config directory
```

I checked out the config directory under my domain and there was a suspicious file called `config.xml`.  Within this file is the configuration for the weblogic nodes and where you want to put your JDPA config:

```
<server>
  <name>my-target-machine</name>
  ...
  <server-start>
    ...
    <arguments>(your other config stuff) -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n</arguments>
```